# Long Running Tasks - Best Practice - ASP.NET 4.0, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

What is the recommended approach to dealing with process which take a long time to execute? I don't want to simply run it on the server since the page will time out.

I browsed the web and found multiple approaches - AJAX, Threading, Web Services... (none of which I have experience with)

What is the best practice method of dealing with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One transparent and reliable way is to implement desired task along with processing queue as WebService. Thus, on client-side you can simply send request to webserver, receive some id in return in order to check the result later.

Everything else depends on how rich user-experience you are trying to implement. You can simply let user to refresh control or entire page from time to time by pressing a button. Or implement ajax-based control that sends requests and checks for the results from time to time by itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned, I did come across web services as an option. I'm specifically looking to know if this is best practice or not. Once I know it is, I would look further into it (would I use the new Web API?) My situation is the user will be uploading large excel files to the server and adding records to the DB.

Comment: Have a look on this also: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you're just trying to do a long-running task, a Windows Service is perfect for this.  No, not a web service but an old-school Windows Service.  When somebody uploads an Excel your Windows Service can be monitoring a directory using FileWatcher, and then execute the import process automatically.  That way you aren't limiting your process to ASP.NET and the IIS Worker processes, which can be recycled for any number of reasons.  It sounds like your app really needs to be outside of IIS.  The upload process can be a simple web front end to put that file into that directory that is monitored by your Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you can just set up a WebService (or, more accurately, a [WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) since regular XML WebServices are deprecated), like pukipuki mentioned.

If the long-running process is complicated (many steps, very intensive, something that might be farmed off to other servers) or needs to be robust (the job may fail and needs to be retried, etc) you may want to look into working some form of Message Queuing to control the flow into and out of the service performing the long-running process. Message Queuing is certainly overkill in some situations, but it's also a nice framework that provides message storage, persistence, and flow control so you don't have to build it all yourself. [Here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c19563) is a pretty good overview of how to use MSMQ with ASP.NET (I'm sorry, but the sample code appears to be VB and not C#).